# Airflow: Pass the previous Tuesday from an execution date to a BashOperator

Tags: airflow

I have a dag that runs weekly on Sundays. There's one task, a `BashOperator`, set up as follows:

```
t = BashOperator(
   task_id='print_date',
   bash_command="echo Previous Tuesday is: "

def get_latest_build_date(dt):
   bd = dt + relativedelta(weekday=TU(-1))
   return bd.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

How can I pass the current execution date to the `get_latest_build_date` function?

`bash_command="echo Previous Tuesday is: {{ get_latest_build_date(ds) }}`
will not work with the jinja templating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `user_defined_macros` of `DAG`.

```
def get_latest_build_date(dt):
   bd = dt + relativedelta(weekday=TU(-1))
   return bd.strftime('%Y%m%d')

with DAG('name',
         ...,
         user_defined_macros={'prior_tues': get_latest_build_date},) as dag:

  t = BashOperator(
     task_id='print_date',
     bash_command="echo Previous Tuesday is: {{ prior_tues(execution_date) }}"
```